# DRF - Nested serializer disappears after parent is_valid() call

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

### TLDR; (full description below)

**Valid field with nested serializer is dropped upon validation of parent serializer.** I read some StackOverflow posts about similar cases, but there the field was dropped because of being `read_only=True` which is not my case.

After POSTing valid object to `CreateParentView(generics.CreateAPIView)` I get `Http 400 Bad request` error. I ended up debugging the `create()` method.

```
# parsed_data is a QueryDict prepared from request.POST and request.FILES 
#   to fit the nested serializers format. 

-> serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
(Pdb) parsed_data.keys()
odict_keys(['parent_field_1', 'parent_field_2', 'parent_field_3', 'child'])

(Pdb) from .serializers import CreateChildSerializer; 
      ch = parsed_data.get('child'); 
      new_child = CreateChildSerializer(data = ch);

(Pdb) new_child.is_valid()
True

(Pdb) new_child.errors
{}

# the parent serializer is invalid and drops the 'child' key
(Pdb) serializer.is_valid(); 
False

(Pdb) serializer.data.keys()
odict_keys(['parent_field_1', 'parent_field_2', 'parent_field_3'])
```

The response is `400 (Bad Request), "{"child":["This field is required."]}"`
Dafuq, I just provided you with that, and you, sir, dropped it :-(

### End Of TLDR;

Okay, lets have a look on the View, the Serializer and the Model.
I'm using a toy model, my real one is too verbose to reproduce here.

Lets start with the `models.py` - the `Child` and `Parent` models are `OneToOneField` relationship.

```
# models.py
class Parent(models.Model):
    objects = ParentManager()

    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent_field_1 = models.BooleanField()
    parent_field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    parent_field_3 = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Child(models.Model):
    objects = ChildManager()

    parent = models.OneToOneField('Parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    child_field_1 = ...
```

The serializers are basically the  [DRF guide approach](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations)  for nested serializers.

```
# serializers.py    
class CreateParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    child = CreateChildSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('parent_field_1', 'parent_field_2', 'parent_field_3', 'child')

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        child_data = validated_data.pop('child')
        user = self.context['request'].user
        parent = Parent.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)

        Child.objects.create(parent=parent, **child_data)

        return parent
```

And finally the view.

```
# views.py
class CreateParentView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CreateParentSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        parsed_data = self.parse_request_data(request)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=parsed_data)
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def parse_request_data(self, request):
        data_dict = dict(request.data)

        # renaming keys, adding FILES to reproduce required structure, verbose and irrelevant

        parsed_data = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
        parsed_data.update(data_dict)

        return parsed_data
```

Im out of ideas :X

Comment: What is the value of the `child` key?  Maybe the _key_ is present, but the _value_ is empty or otherwise invalid...

Comment: @JohnGordon the `child` value is a `dict` with 100% valid `Child` data. Validating it under `Pdb` debug raises no errors.

Comment: `validated_data.pop('child')` removes the `child` key from `validated_data`.  Could that be the cause?

Comment: @JohnGordon Thats intentional :-) and that code is not executed - the validation fails, raises error and the CreateParentSerializer.create() is not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, posting here works like a charm...

I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/2919) GitHub thread for this exact problem.

> QueryDict is only used for multipart input which doesn't support nested objects.

I had to transfer a nested object with FILES, thus used multipart/form-data and needed the `parse_request_data(request)` method. After modifying the method to return an ordinary `dict` instead of a `QueryDict` everything went on smoothly.

```
def parse_request_data(self, request):
        data_dict = dict(request.data)

        # renaming keys, adding FILES to reproduce required structure, verbose and irrelevant

        ### parsed_data = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
        ### parsed_data.update(data_dict)

        return data_dict
```